# Update control from another thread (VB.NET) WPF

Tags: wpf, vb.net, thread-safety

I am creating a test application for the first time in WPF. I am trying to update a listbox that was created in the Thread UI from another thread (non-UI thread). The problem I am facing is regardless of the all the advice I found in the other threads, it doesn't seem to work. It worked for textboxes just fine but it will not work no matter what for this listbox.

I already tried creating an actual control that is located on the window itself (in case declaring it in the code would be the cause) but it didn't work.

If I try using BeginInvoke, nothing happens at runtime but if I try using Invoke instead, the application just freeze forever. Here is the code I came up with so far.

Button Click Event :

```
Dim TableList As New ListBox
 If GetTableList(connection, TableList, DatabaseName, TxtBx_Tasklist) = 0 Then
            MsgBox(TableList.Items.Count)
 Else
 msgbox("FAIL")
 End If
```

GetTableList Function :

```
             Dim ThreadResult As Integer
    Dim Thread As New System.Threading.Thread(Sub()
                                                  ThreadResult = _GetTableList(SQLConnection, Listbox, DatabaseName, tasklist)
                                                  'Thread.Sleep(5000)
                                              End Sub)
    Thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA)
    Thread.Start()
    Do Until Thread.ThreadState = System.Threading.ThreadState.Stopped
    Loop
    If ThreadResult = 0 Then

        Return 0
    Else
        Return 1
    End If
```

_GetTableList Function :

```
       Try

        'Make sure listbox is empty
        Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(New Action(Sub()
                                                                  listbox.Items.Clear()
                                                              End Sub), DispatcherPriority.Background)
        'Declare required components for the SQL operation
        Dim command As New MySqlCommand("SHOW tables;")
        Dim adapter As New MySqlDataAdapter
        Dim data As MySqlDataReader
        Dim TableList As New ListBox

        'Open connection to the server
        SQLConnection.Open()

        'Execute the command
        command.Connection = SQLConnection
        adapter.SelectCommand = command
        data = command.ExecuteReader

        'Update the tasklist control
        Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(New Action(Sub()
                                                                  tasklist.AppendText("Getting table list for database " & DatabaseName & "...")
                                                              End Sub), DispatcherPriority.Background)
        'Process data returned from query and store it in a temporary
        While data.Read
            If data.HasRows Then
                TableList.Items.Add(data(0))
                'MsgBox(data(0) & " " & listbox.Items.Count)
            End If
        End While

        'Update the tablelist
        For Each items In TableList.Items
            listbox.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(New Action(Sub()
                                                          listbox.Items.Add(items.ToString)
                                                      End Sub))
        Next

        'Closed SQL connections
        SQLConnection.Close()
        SQLConnection.Dispose()

        'Update tasklist control
        tasklist.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(New Action(Sub()
                                                       tasklist.AppendText("...Done! " & listbox.Items.Count & " tables found." & vbNewLine)
                                                   End Sub), DispatcherPriority.Background)

        'Return 0 to confirm nothing went wrong
        Return 0
    Catch ex As MySqlException
        MsgBox("An error occured while getting the list of tables : " & ex.Number & " , " & ex.Message)
        Return 1
    End Try
```

Updating the tasklist control (which is a textbox) using the BeginInvoke works well but for some reason, updating the listbox doesn't work well.

Any ideas what I am missing to have the listbox updated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're planning on blocking until the thread completes, why are you using a thread? Do it in the GUI thread. If you wanted it in the background, don't block and wait for the thread to complete.

`Invoke` deadlocks because the delegate you pass to `Invoke` is run on the GUI thread, but the GUI thread is waiting for the background thread to complete and thus is not processing messages.

Comment: Thanks for the response however it seems I forgot to remove the "system.windows.threading.dispatcher.run()" part. It was an attempt at resolving my issue but did not help unfortunately.

Comment: That isn't the part you need to remove. The part you need to remove is: `Do Until Thread.ThreadState = System.Threading.ThreadState.Stopped` and following. Stop blocking your UI thread.

Comment: Oh! It totally make sense! In Windows Forms, I used to do a application.doevent() but it doesn't seem to work in WPF. Thanks for the help!